# .NET Docker image tags for rollForward latestPatch

Tags: .net, docker, sdk, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2020

We are using .NET 6 with global.json specifying the required SDK version. **Which Docker image tag should we use to achieve the same roll-forward behavior?**

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.200"
  }
}
```

We rely on the default roll-forward behavior, which preserves the major, minor, and [feature band](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/releases-and-support#feature-bands-sdk-only) while it rolls forward the patch version automatically. This corresponds to [`"rollForward": "latestPatch"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x#rollforward). All potentially breaking changes are prevented while security patches are allowed. Different patches of the same feature band are in-place updates and they cannot be installed side-by-side, anyway. We upgrade feature bands manually, in a controlled way.

Our apps are containerized, using [the official .NET Docker images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/official-net-docker-images) as their base. The docs [recommend using the tag that fixes major and minor version](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/build-in-sdk-container.md#pull-sdk-image), but they still roll forward the feature band automatically.

> It is recommended to pull the SDK image before running the appropriate command. This ensures that you get the latest patch version of the SDK. Use the following command:
>
> ```
> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
> ```

If we use the 6.0 tag for the base image, our build will break when a new feature band is released as the roll forward policy fixes the feature band. If we use the 6.0.200 tag for the base image, the build will not break, but we will not receive the security patches automatically -- we will need to update the tag for each patch release manually.

Is there a way to **keep the build working reliably while automatically getting security patches** of the SDK in the Docker images? We build our apps using Azure Pipelines in Azure DevOps Server 2020u1, using YAML pipelines.

Comment: There are no feature band tags. As you've said, you either get the latest feature band with the `6.0` tag or you have to use a patch-specific tag like `6.0.200`. Please log an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker describing your needs.

Comment: So far, we opted to use patch-specific tags and upgrade manually with each bi-weekly release of our software. We will see how it goes. If it proves to be too much work for our small team, we will switch to the latest feature band tag and roll-forward policy latestFeature. I hope to find time to file the issue on GitHub soon.

Comment: We pull the images from [MCR](https://github.com/microsoft/containerregistry), so we can use https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/sdk/tags/list to find if any newer tag matching '^6\.0\.2\d\d$' exists.